# Hello, how can I fix my mat-form-field, when I zoom in my screen it losing width

Tags: html, css

HTML
Here my code, I need to fix mat-form-field width with input width end when zoom in or out screen, fix they width.

```html
<label class="label-inline"></label>
<div class="div-inline">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type"></mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<label class="label-inline"></label>
<div class="div-inline">
  <input [disabled]="disableField" class="form-control" />
</div>

<button class="btn" (click)="save()">{{"SAVE" | translate}}</button>
```

CSS

```css
label {
  width: 15%;
}

::ng-deep mat-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: -1.25em;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-infix {
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

input:disabled {
  background: #dddddd;
}

mat-form-field {
  min-width: 53.1%;
}
```

[Here when I zoom out it losing width, how can I fix it with input width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMBgv.png)

Comment: mat-form-field {
  width: auto;
}

Comment: Try the above CSS on mat-form-field. remove min-width and use width: instead. Try also with width:100%; if width:auto; doesn't work

Comment: Let me know if this quick-fix works. If this doesn't work. Add  padding-right:0; to mat-form-field as well

Comment: width: auto; works fine. Thanks

Comment: Shall I answer it Mate. And you can then accept this :)

Comment: Have answered your question. If my answer has helped you. The best way to say thanks is voting on the answer and accepting it, by clicking the tick icons just left to the answer. This helps other developers with the same issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the width is in `%`. This is creating the problem. Try

```
mat-form-field { width: auto; }
```